# Wicket atmosphere initialization exception

Tags: wicket, atmosphere

I have the following setup:
wicket: 6.1.0
wicket-atmosphere: 0.4

(via Maven)

On Application.init() I get a NullPointerException during instantiation of EventBus

```
    new EventBus(this);
```

Exception:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.wicket.atmosphere.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:105)
```

This is caused because the  method

```
    public synchronized static BroadcasterFactory getDefault()
```

delivers null (the protected static member "factory" is not initialized).

How do I use Wicket/Atmosphere properly? Did I forget something to initialize? I'm starting Wicket as a ServletFilter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AtmosphereTest</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.atmosphere.wicket.Application</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>development</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignorePaths</param-name>
        <param-value>/css,/js,/images,/icons</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AtmosphereTest</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I don't have a atmosphere configuration, do I need one?

Thanks

Comment: This seems likely to be an omission in your atmosphere initialization.  Can you show your web.xml and atmosphere.xml?  This [email thread](http://osdir.com/ml/users-wicket.apache.org/2012-06/msg00248.html) may be useful.

Comment: Added web.xml extract, I dont have a atmosphere.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this email](http://osdir.com/ml/users-wicket.apache.org/2012-06/msg00248.html) from the users-wicket list, you should set up the `AtmosphereServlet` in your web.xml and supply it with an atmosphere.xml configuration file that tells atmosphere how to load the `WicketFilter` instead of configuring `WicketFilter` directly in your web.xml.

I haven't used atmosphere, so I can't really vouch for this, but it sounds sensible.

The email referenced above has  web.xml and atmosphere.xml configurations that might help you get this set up.

Comment: Yes that was the trick. One has to configure the atmosphere servlet in the web.xml. Then you have to configure the Application class in the atmosphere.xml