# Attempting to implement 1.6 EventBus with Wicket on Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, websocket, wicket

Wanted to try out the new EventBus in Wicket 6 but I am having trouble getting Tomcat7 to deploy it correctly...

Any kind of implementation of the  results in some kind of error.
The latest try is by using wicket 1.6, Tomcat7 and Wicket-atmosphere 0.3 and I think I am almost there now!

Anyways, when attempting to deploy the module im getting a "NoClassDefFound from Tomcat...

```
dec 07, 2012 10:50:54 EM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
Info: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.catalina.websocket.WsOutbound.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to at
tempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1597)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        at org.atmosphere.container.version.TomcatWebSocket.close(TomcatWebSocket.java:129)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse$1.close(AtmosphereResponse.java:545)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.cancelled(AsynchronousProcessor.java:568)
        at org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport.cancelled(BlockingIOCometSupport.java:165)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor$AsynchronousProcessorHook.closed(AsynchronousProcessor.java:634)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.close(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:262)
        at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketHandler.onClose(TomcatWebSocketHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.doOnClose(StreamInbound.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.closeOutboundConnection(StreamInbound.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.onData(StreamInbound.java:161)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessor.upgradeDispatch(UpgradeProcessor.java:83)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

dec 07, 2012 10:50:54 EM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler process
Allvarlig: null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/websocket/WsOutbound
        at org.atmosphere.container.version.TomcatWebSocket.close(TomcatWebSocket.java:129)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponse.close(AtmosphereResponse.java:785)
        at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.cancel(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:830)
        at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.close(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:272)
        at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketHandler.onClose(TomcatWebSocketHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.doOnClose(StreamInbound.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.closeOutboundConnection(StreamInbound.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound.onData(StreamInbound.java:161)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessor.upgradeDispatch(UpgradeProcessor.java:83)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Kinda asking two questions here...

1: What causes this error? Google rly isnt helping much this time :S

2: Is there a WORKING complete guide/tutorial on how to get Wicket-atmosphere working?

Don't mean to be vague in my question, but I don't really know what other information that can be relevant here.

My configurations are pretty much identical to the ones given in the post(and links) from [Wicket atmosphere initialization exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100508/wicket-atmosphere-initialization-exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recently learned, a NoClassDefFoundException is a nasty one. In my case, eclipse ate my workspace. Checking out the very same code into a new one helped, while refreshing the old one over and over didn't. I was able to find the class but Java couldn't. Since your error comes from Tomcat and not eclipse just downloading a fresh one (and redeploying the app) might help. I know, this is scary and I don't like stuff like this at all but this was the only way to get things running again.

Comment: How I hate these kinds of problems... You never learn anything from them :S